# Counting Rotations [Unity C#]

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

Trying to figure out a way to increment the rotation count after the spinner passes 360 degrees. Though this never works because eulerAngles reset at 360. What's a good way to do this? I tried doing > 355, but that is't a great solution.

```
            Spinner.transform.Rotate(0, 0, speed);
            float angleZ = Spinner.rotation.eulerAngles.z;

            if (angleZ > 360)
            {
                Rotations++;
            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to check the angle before & after the rotation.

According to the documentation "speed" is the number of degrees to rotate, so add the integer division of speed by 360 to Rotations & then check for the final value having been reset.

```
float angleZ1 = Spinner.rotation.eulerAngles.z;
Spinner.transform.Rotate(0, 0, speed);
float angleZ2 = Spinner.rotation.eulerAngles.z;
float angleZDiff = angleZ2 - angleZ1;


Rotations += (int)(speed / 360);
if ((speed >0) && (angleZDiff < 0))
    Rotations++
else if ((speed < 0) && (angleZDiff > 0))
    Rotations--;
```

Comment: This makes sense. What if the speed is too fast?

Comment: If the speed is too fast - ie causing more than 360 rotation then you would miss rotations - for example if the speed caused a rotation of 361 degrees, because the eulerAngle is "reset" at 360 then the rotation would only appear to be 1 degree.

Comment: What method could you use to avoid this?

Comment: Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html) - your speed parameter is the number of degrees you are rotating - so you can add an integer division of that value - I have modified the code above.

Comment: I see. Well, the code works better now, though not 100%. I'm guessing it's because my speed is constantly decreasing with "friction" and the only way to increase it is to click on the screen.

For example, when I tap, the object does half a rotation and the speed is 0 again. Though using EulerAngles, I know the exact angle of rotation and it works fine when it hits 350 and is logged. But when the speed is insane, it's pretty impossible.

Comment: I made an edit to the code and ignored if speed > 0. It works much better now.

Answer (score 0):

You can divide the angle by 360 and cast it to an int to get the number of rotations.

```
Rotations = (int)(angle / 360f);
```

Comment: This just gives the angle - not the number of rotations

Comment: @PaulF sorry it's actually division, I've fixed my answer.

Comment: If you read the question - OP says the eulerAngles always reset at 360 - so the value will always be >= 0 & < 360 - which is why there is a problem.

Comment: You could add two colliders at varying distances then the collision check points will give extra data points that are correct regardless of the speed.

Answer (score 0):

You could add two colliders at varying distances then the collision check points will give extra data points that are correct regardless of the speed